# Delete a single array of object?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

I am not sure if both of these works to delete:

```
p = new int[1];

delete p
```

and

```
delete [] p;
```

If both works, what is the difference between the above two `delete`s?

Comment: The `new` and `delete` must match, or you have undefined behavior. Seeming to work on one platform is a possible outcome of undefined behavior, as is crashing everything terribly. Don't do it.

Answer (score 4):

An array of one instance is still an array. There is simply not a special case, so you need to treat it as an array and not a single object. Non-array `delete` may crash.

An array of objects may be preceded by a number signifying the size of the array. If that's the case, `delete[]`, not `delete`, is smart enough to pass the correct pointer to `free`.

Answer (score 2):

They are **not** the same. Even though `delete p` would compile but could potentially cause problems at runtime.

`delete p` will invoke `operator delete(void*)` where as `delete []` will call `operator delete[](void*)`. The default behavior is for `delete[]` to call `delete` but if a custom operator for `delete []` has been implemented, it won't be called if you just call `delete` and you'll have a problem (probably a silent one).

Good rule of thumb is if you used `[]` in the `new`, use it in the `delete`.

Comment: Not a rule of thumb, a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

`delete p` deletes only one element. `delete [] p` deletes an array. If you use `new type[]`, then use `delete []`.

If you're `new` has a `[]`, then `delete` has a `[]`.

By the way there has to be an exact dupliate of this somewhere.